# Code Prints To DOM When Dynamically Inserting Inline Scripts With Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, inject

I'm trying to insert a chart dynamically with javascript. I found an example of how to do such a thing and it almost works. The chart loads but then underneath the chart, part of the Javascript used to display the chart actually shows as text on the page. It otherwise works fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tvTest"></div>
<script>
/* helpers
 */

// runs an array of async functions in sequential order
function seq (arr, callback, index) {
  // first call, without an index
  if (typeof index === 'undefined') {
    index = 0
  }

  arr[index](function () {
    index++
    if (index === arr.length) {
      callback()
    } else {
      seq(arr, callback, index)
    }
  })
}

// trigger DOMContentLoaded
function scriptsDone () {
  var DOMContentLoadedEvent = document.createEvent('Event')
  DOMContentLoadedEvent.initEvent('DOMContentLoaded', true, true)
  document.dispatchEvent(DOMContentLoadedEvent)
}

/* script runner
 */

function insertScript ($script, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script')
  s.type = 'text/javascript'
  if ($script.src) {
    s.onload = callback
    s.onerror = callback
    s.src = $script.src
  } else {
    s.textContent = $script.innerText
  }

  // re-insert the script tag so it executes.
  document.head.appendChild(s)

  // clean-up
  $script.parentNode.removeChild($script)

  // run the callback immediately for inline scripts
  if (!$script.src) {
    callback()
  }
}

// https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html
var runScriptTypes = [
  'application/javascript',
  'application/ecmascript',
  'application/x-ecmascript',
  'application/x-javascript',
  'text/ecmascript',
  'text/javascript',
  'text/javascript1.0',
  'text/javascript1.1',
  'text/javascript1.2',
  'text/javascript1.3',
  'text/javascript1.4',
  'text/javascript1.5',
  'text/jscript',
  'text/livescript',
  'text/x-ecmascript',
  'text/x-javascript'
]

function runScripts ($container) {
  // get scripts tags from a node
  var $scripts = $container.querySelectorAll('script')
  var runList = []
  var typeAttr

  [].forEach.call($scripts, function ($script) {
    typeAttr = $script.getAttribute('type')

    // only run script tags without the type attribute
    // or with a javascript mime attribute value
    if (!typeAttr || runScriptTypes.indexOf(typeAttr) !== -1) {
      runList.push(function (callback) {
        insertScript($script, callback)
      })
    }
  })

  // insert the script tags sequentially
  // to preserve execution order
  seq(runList, scriptsDone)
}


$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var htmlContent = `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            new TradingView.widget({
            "width": 500,
            "height": 400,
            "symbol": "BINANCE:AMBETH",
            "interval": "60",
            "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
            "theme": "Dark",
            "style": "1",
            "locale": "en",
            "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
            "enable_publishing": false,
            "allow_symbol_change": true,
            "hideideas": true
            });
            </script>`;


    var $container = document.querySelector('#tvTest');
    $container.innerHTML = htmlContent;
    runScripts($container);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run that, the chart displays and just underneath it, I see the code `var $container = document.querySelector('#tvTest'); $container.innerHTML = htmlContent; runScripts($container); });` as text in the DOM. How can I get it to render the chart without printing any code to the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this trading view library appends to the body. You can override that by passing "container_id" property. Here is a simplified example of your code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tvTest"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget({
  "container_id": "tvTest", // THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED
  "width": 500,
  "height": 400,
  "symbol": "BINANCE:AMBETH",
  "interval": "60",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "Dark",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "hideideas": true
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah but now the chart replaces the whole DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `<\/script>` inside of the string template

Comment: It appears as though the injection script wasn't working before and the template was just causing the chart code to render in-place. Now that I escapes the slashes, the code runs but the whole page now goes blank and the only thing on the entire page is now the injected chart. How to fix this?

Comment: you could open devtools and see if there are any errors. Notice that you need to escape the <\/script> in two places.